# Java virtual machine (JVM) - In what language JVM coded?

Tags: java, jvm

Is JVM software based? If so in which language is JVM coded?

Comment: @bignose: thanks for your correction, hope its fine now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost all JVMs are implemented in software. However, a JVM is anything that interprets [Java bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) in a manner that complies with the [JVM specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html), and there are some [hardware-based JVMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor) as well.

Comment: There are even semi-hardware implementations of JVM. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle

Comment: If it's implemented in hardware, it's not really a "virtual" machine anymore, is it?

Comment: @Michael, haha, no, I guess not.... it's kind of like how people say "ATM machine" instead of ATM, but I think the OP would still like to  know that Java can be interpreted at the hardware level.

Comment: except that it is often difficult to know where the boundary is.  For instance, micro or nano-coded machines, machines where part of the "instruction set" is implemented by trapping to a software implementation, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Java Virtual Machine is a [formal specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html) for **how a virtual machine needs to behave** by interpreting bytecode as instructions in the virtual machine's operation set.

If there's some mechanism that interprets the bytecode and behaves the right way, it *is* a JVM, no matter how it's implemented.

That means a JVM *can* be implemented in a program, or it can equally well be implemented in hardware. If you want to know which is the case, you need to be talking about [some specific implementation](https://dmoztools.net/Computers/Programming/Languages/Java/Implementations/).

Answer (score 4):

Kind of... it's more like a standard that has resulted in a number of pieces of software.  You cannot be 100% certain what language the JVM is written in, but in most cases, I'd bet it was written in C/C++.

Comment: FWIW, it is written in C++ using Visual Studio and gcc. One of the Java engineers is a neighbor :)

Comment: @Michael, there is no single JVM. The Sun Java JVM is one implementation... there are others, including the one used on Mac OS X, and there are a handful of open source JVMs out there, as well.

Answer (score 1):

To answer what I think is your question, the JVM is written in C++. The majority of the Java libraries are written in Java, however.

Same applies to .NET: The code CLR/VM is written in C++, but the class libs are written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

JVM stands for "Java Virtual Machine". It's a virtualised environment that provides Java applications with a way of running in the same way across multiple different physical environments.

The idea is that Java code is compiled and is executed by the JVM. The JVM provides the same look and feel for the actual code regardless of whether it's being run on a massively parallel mainframe or a single processor PC running Windows XP.

These days the JVM is being used for languages other than Java (Scala, for example).

Comment: @Andrew could you please specify whether its a software

Answer (score 0):

```
JVM is a specification that provides runtime environment in which java bytecode can be executed.
```

Jvm Interprets your **bytecode into Machine Understandable code**.

The JVM performs following operation:

```
 - Loads code
 - Verifies code
 - Executes code
 - Provides runtime environment
```

To do this a code has to be written, 
So Implementation of specifications is done here(sun provides mostly).
This implemetation is **JRE**.

JVM ALSO TELL HOW FOLLOWING THINGS MUST HAPPEN:

```
 - Memory area
 - Class file format
 - Register set
 - Garbage-collected heap
 - Fatal error reporting etc.
```

So This all is Software,find detail working Here [JVM Details](http://www.javatpoint.com/internal-details-of-jvm)

Comment: No, the *JVM Specification* is a specification. The JVM is an abstraction that is defined by its specification, and can be realized in software, hardware, or anything in between. It's also loosely used to refer to a running process.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Virtual Machine is a program whose purpose is to execute other programs.

The JVM has two primary functions: to **allow Java programs to run on any device** or operating system (known as the "Write once, run anywhere" principle), and to **manage and optimize program memory**. When Java was released in 1995, all computer programs were written to a specific operating system, and program memory was managed by the software developer.

[image]

JVM is a **software specification**. In a somewhat circular fashion, the JVM spec highlights that its implementation details are not defined within the spec, in order to allow for maximum creativity in its realization.

So, all the JVM has to do is run Java programs correctly. Sounds simple, might even look simple from outside, but it is a massive undertaking, especially given the power and flexibility of the Java language.

Check out the article to [learn more about JVM](https://javatutorial.net/jvm-explained).